# Remove luks encryption from single partition of disk

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot, encryption, luks

I've been trying to figure out dualbooting windows 10 on my ubuntu laptop for a few says now - my 1tb hdd is encrypted with LUKS and after battling finding a way to partition it, I was finally able to use kde partition manager on a live usb to split the 930gb drive into ~830g (sda3) and ~100gb (sda4, the new ntfs partition). sda1 and 2 are just swap/misc, the os is on sda3, the one I'm trying to mess around with.

However, now that I have the two partitions, they're both still stuck under sda3 when I load up the windows installer - I still see it as 930gb.

My assumption is that sda4 is still encrypted and is hidden under sda3, so how can I remove just that partition's encryption to make it visible to the windows installer?

Comment: Do not know LVM, but you have to shrink volume with LVM tools then shrink partition with partition tools. http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/252204/how-to-shrink-ubuntu-lvm-logical-and-physical-volumes Be sure to have good backups as Windows does not always correctly see Linux partitions. Also if BIOS/MBR, you must install Windows in BIOS boot mode to a primary NTFS partition with boot flag. If UEFI, it wants multiple partitions, but will reuse existing ESP.

Comment: @oldfred I've been able to shrink the partition, but I have the issue that the new partition (sda4) is still stuck inside the LUKS container and I'm not finding a way to move it outside of it.

Comment: You would have to remove it and further shrink the volume & the partition the volume is contained in. Then you can create a new partition outside the volume. If you used MBR partitioning, then you may also have the 4 primary partition limit which is a separate issue. If gpt, then you can create additional partitions without issue outside the LVM.